# process shared pthread_cond_t doesn't work in gcc 8.4 but works in gcc 4.8.5

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads, posix, glibc

Recently I upgraded my OS from RHEL 7.6(gcc 4.8.5) to RHEL 8.4(gcc 8.4) and I'm facing issues related to process synchronization using `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`. The reason I'm not using C++ `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` is because they doesn't support synchronization between processes. This used to work well in `gcc 4.8.5` but not in `gcc 8.4`. This is my code

Binary_Semaphore.h

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEMAPHORE_H
#define BINARY_SEMAPHORE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct binary_semaphore_attr {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cvar;
    bool flag;
};

class Binary_Semaphore {

    struct binary_semaphore_attr *bin_sem_attr;
    const std::string bin_sem_attr_shm_ID;

    const bool is_process_shared;
    const bool is_to_be_created;

public:
    Binary_Semaphore(const std::string& bin_sem_attr_shm_ID, const bool is_process_shared, const bool is_to_be_created);
    ~Binary_Semaphore();
    
    void post();
    void wait();

    template<typename T>
    static void create_shared_memory(T **shm, const std::string& shm_ID, const bool is_to_be_created, const int o_flags, const int mode) {
        int shm_fd;
        if ((shm_fd = shm_open(shm_ID.c_str(), o_flags, mode)) == -1) {
            std::cerr << "shm_open failed with " << shm_ID << "\n";

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (is_to_be_created) {
            if (ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(T)) == -1) {
                std::cerr << "ftruncate failed with " << shm_ID << "\n";

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if ((*shm = reinterpret_cast<T*>(mmap(nullptr, sizeof(T), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0))) == MAP_FAILED) {
            std::cerr << "mmap failed with " << shm_ID << "\n";

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        close(shm_fd);
    }
};

#endif
```

Binary_Semaphore.cpp

```
#include "Binary_Semaphore.h"

Binary_Semaphore::Binary_Semaphore(const std::string& bin_sem_attr_shm_ID, const bool is_process_shared, const bool is_to_be_created) : bin_sem_attr_shm_ID(bin_sem_attr_shm_ID), is_process_shared(is_process_shared), is_to_be_created(is_to_be_created) {
    /* set binary semaphore attribute */
    if (is_to_be_created) {
        if (is_process_shared) {
            create_shared_memory(&bin_sem_attr, bin_sem_attr_shm_ID, is_to_be_created, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);

            /* set mutex shared between processes */
            pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr;
            pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
            pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
            pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);
            pthread_mutex_init(&bin_sem_attr->mutex, &mutex_attr);
            pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutex_attr);

            /* set cvar shared between processes */
            pthread_condattr_t cvar_attr;
            pthread_condattr_init(&cvar_attr);
            pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cvar_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
            pthread_cond_init(&bin_sem_attr->cvar, &cvar_attr);
            pthread_condattr_destroy(&cvar_attr);
        } else
            bin_sem_attr = new binary_semaphore_attr();
    } else {
        if (is_process_shared)
            create_shared_memory(&bin_sem_attr, bin_sem_attr_shm_ID, is_to_be_created, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP);
    }
}

Binary_Semaphore::~Binary_Semaphore() {
    if (is_to_be_created) {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&bin_sem_attr->mutex);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&bin_sem_attr->cvar);
    }

    if (is_process_shared) {
        munmap(bin_sem_attr, sizeof(binary_semaphore_attr));
        shm_unlink(bin_sem_attr_shm_ID.c_str());
    }
}

void Binary_Semaphore::post() {
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&bin_sem_attr->mutex) == EOWNERDEAD)
        pthread_mutex_consistent(&bin_sem_attr->mutex);
    bin_sem_attr->flag = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bin_sem_attr->mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&bin_sem_attr->cvar);
}

void Binary_Semaphore::wait() {
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&bin_sem_attr->mutex) == EOWNERDEAD)
        pthread_mutex_consistent(&bin_sem_attr->mutex);
    while (!bin_sem_attr->flag) {
        if (pthread_cond_wait(&bin_sem_attr->cvar, &bin_sem_attr->mutex) == EOWNERDEAD)
            pthread_mutex_consistent(&bin_sem_attr->mutex);
    }
    bin_sem_attr->flag = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bin_sem_attr->mutex);
}
```

First_Process.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include "Binary_Semaphore.h"

int main() {
    static const std::string BSEM = R"(/BSEM)";
    
    Binary_Semaphore *binary_sem = new Binary_Semaphore(BSEM, true, true);
    while (true) {
        binary_sem->post();
        std::cout << "signal posted" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1LL));
    }
}
```

Second_Process.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Binary_Semaphore.h"

int main() {
    static const std::string BSEM = R"(/BSEM)";
    
    Binary_Semaphore *binary_sem = new Binary_Semaphore(BSEM, true, false);
    while (true) {
        binary_sem->wait();
        std::cout << "signal received" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Run first process followed by second process and then abruptly terminate second process using Ctrl^C and then rerun second process, no more prints on the terminal(both first process and second process).

Did anybody face same kind of issue with latest gcc versions?

Comment: Unrelated: Looks like you're leaking your `binary_sem`s. The program's going to exit and the OS will clean up, but you won't get the warm-and-fuzzy  feeling of knowing the destructor ran.

Comment: Shouldn't `while (bin_sem_attr->flag))` be volatile? Can you try with `volatile bool flag;` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk But why signalling process(first process) stops printing, since it doesn't block on anything other than getting mutex locked.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, it shouldn't be. The mutex protects `flag`.

Comment: What kernel versions do you have on both machines? Would you be able to test newer kernel with gcc4.8.5? What I see is that `first_process` is blocked on `pthread_cond_signal(` syscall. That happens most probably because `second_process` get's killed in the middle of `pthread_cond_wait` (the mutex is actually unlocked there, because `pthread_cond_wait` unlocks it).

Comment: What happens if you set O_EXCL when creating the shared memory segment?  In my experience, "leftover" shared synchronization objects introduce a lot of room for error in code that doesn't scrupulously clean up.  (Much less importantly, you can `close()` that shm fd as soon as you `mmap` it — you don't need to keep the fd around.)

Comment: So I created a repo with the code [on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow_shread_pthread_cond_/-/tree/master) . It [works on docker gcc:6](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow_shread_pthread_cond_/-/jobs/1699559148) and [fails with gcc:7](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/stackoverflow_shread_pthread_cond_/-/jobs/1699559149).

Comment: @KamilCuk do you think it's a `gcc` compiler bug?

Comment: No, it's unrelated to compiler. if any, it's glibc bug , but I do not know if this is intended behavior or not. I believe talking to glibc people might be a good idea. Also, the link https://chat.stackoverflow.com//transcript/238375 .

Comment: I don't think it explains the specific problem you describe, but your `Binary_Semaphore` destructor is an accident waiting to happen.  If you have multiple `Binary_Semaphore` instances connected to the same underlying process-shared mutex and condition variable, then the first one to be destructed will tear down the mutex and condition variable while they may still be in use by other processes, or even by another `Binary_Semaphore` instance in the same process.

Comment: @JohnBollinger only the creator process(First_Process.cpp) will destroy the underlying process-shared mutex and condition variable of `Binary_Semaphore`. But in my case I'm abruptly terminating the `Second_Process.cpp` which is not a creator process, so I don't think it's going have an impact on underlying process-shared mutex and condition variable of `Binary_Semaphore`

Comment: @Harry, even if you arrange for there to be only one process that tears down the mutex and CV, that does not solve the problem by itself.  In that case, you must also ensure somehow that the process responsible for the tear down in fact does so only after all other processes using those objects have terminated, and that's an exceedingly difficult problem in the general case.

Comment: More directly to the question, are you *sure* that the posted code is exactly what supposedly works as intended on RHEL7?  Including the `while (bin_sem_attr->flag)` in `Binary_Semaphore::wait()`?  Because I don't see how that could do what you want.  The sense of the conditional is reversed.

Comment: Does it resolve the issue for you to change the `pthread_cond_signal()` call to `pthread_cond_broadcast()` in `Binary_Semaphore::post()`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger changing `pthread_cond_signal()` to `pthread_cond_broadcast()` didn't help, issue still exists.

Comment: @KamilCuk like you said it's an issue of `glibc`. You can check this link https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21422. If you've an alternate solution, please do let me know

Answer (score 2):

glibc does not support robust condition variables. (They are not part of POSIX.) You need to re-create the shared memory segment with the condition variables if one of the participating processes terminates abnormally.

Comment: If you've any other alternative solution,  please do let me know.