# Recovering pthread_cond_t & pthread_mutex_t after process termination

Tags: c++, pthreads, ipc, shared-memory

**Hey there!**

I have already looked up similiar problems here, but didn't arrive at a final solution.

In my application, I have two processes running concurrently that need to be synchronized via shared-memory. Currently I'm using a `pthread_mutex_t` & `pthread_cond_t` for that purpose which are put into shared-memory.

This is working fine until process A crashes whilst waiting on the condition. If process A is restarted a deadlock(?) happens in which process A waits on the condition and process B is stuck indefinetly at the call to `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

I read that this may be due to the mutex being in an inconsistent state, but in fact it never seems to be in my program.
I would appreciate if you can tell me if I misunderstood something or if there are alternative approaches on solving this or if it isn't possible at all to guard this case of crashing.

```c++
struct Poller
{
    private:
      std::atomic<bool> waiting;
      pthread_mutex_t mtx;
      pthread_cond_t cnd;

    auto lockMutex() -> void
    {
      // Recover Mutex if any process locking it died unexpectedly
      LOG_DEBUG(info, "AdaptivePoller", "Locking mutex...");
      if(pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx) == EOWNERDEAD) {
        LOG_DEBUG(info, "AdaptivePoller", "Mutex in inconsistent state.");
        if(pthread_mutex_consistent(&mtx) != 0) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Mutex could not be brought back into consistent state.");
        }
      }
    }

    public:
      Poller()
      {
        waiting = false;
        
        pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
        pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);
        pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, &attr);
        pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

        pthread_condattr_t attrcond;
        pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond);
        pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        pthread_cond_init(&cnd, &attrcond);
        pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond);
      }

      auto wait() -> void
      { 
        lockMutex();
        waiting = true;
        LOG_DEBUG(info, "AdaptivePoller", "Start waiting...");
        while(waiting) {
          pthread_cond_wait(&cnd, &mtx);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
      }

      auto notify() -> void
      {    
        lockMutex();
        waiting = false;
        LOG_DEBUG(info, "AdaptivePoller", "Notifying...");
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cnd);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
      }
};
```

Comment: You check for `EOWNERDEAD` from `pthread_mutex_lock`, but not from [`pthread_cond_wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html), which also obtains a lock before returning and can return `EOWNERDEAD`. Let me know (by using `@ikegami` in a comment) if this helps.

Comment: POSIX does not offer a robustness option for its condition variables.  Implementations are known to vary, but in recent glibc, for example, if a process dies while blocked in `pthread_cond_wait()` on a process-shared CV, that CV's state is not recoverable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger 
Thank you for the information!
Do you know/Can you recommend another way to implement a similiar synchronization behaviour like in my application and being able to deal with this corner case properly?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650814/process-shared-pthread-cond-t-doesnt-work-in-gcc-8-4-but-works-in-gcc-4-8-5#69650814 Maybe can be stretched  to a duplicate.

Comment: @Varrick, the synchronization behavior I see is that one or more threads can block themselves until such later time as another thread unblocks all then-waiting threads.  Is that an accurate and sufficient description of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JohnBollinger
If you exchange "threads" for "processes" then it's an accurate description :)
The use-case is especially targeted at being able to have **multiple processes** block themselves until some other process wakes them up. Kind of like a single producer multiple consumer scenario.

Comment: I daresay that "threads" has to be the correct word, but I accept the clarification that it is required to support the threads involved belonging to different processes.  If all the processes involved are single-threaded then this is a distinction without a difference, but as soon as you introduce any multi-threaded processes, the distinction matters.

Comment: @JohnBollinger
Fair point. Let's suppose, that the application wants to serve the case that we have multiple processes which are single-threaded :)

Comment: Is the restarted process A re-initializing the shared mutex and cv?  That'd lead to undefined behavior.  And, perhaps I misunderstand, but I do not see that the mutex-protected predicate is in shared memory (or is otherwise some global state visible to all relevant processes).  Could you flesh out a [mre]?

Comment: @pilcrow Thank you for your reply. No, the shared memory is managed by an independant process so nothing is re-initialized if a proccess using the shared memory is restarted.
The whole struct is indeed in shared memory regardless of what processes using it are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the POSIX API does not define mechanisms sufficient to make your `Poller` wholly robust against all process-failure scenarios.  But you might achieve a situation you consider an improvement by using a SysV semaphore in place of the condition variable and mutex.  Here's an outline:

- a semaphore `can_proceed` provides for threads to block themselves until released.  This semaphore has initial value 0, and threads block themselves by attempting to decrement it.
- a thread releases the currently-blocked processes by incrementing `can_proceed` by the number of blocked processes.  The SysV semaphore API provides an operation for determining how many that is.

The above is not infallible.  At least these cases can occur:

- A waiting process *W* dies after a notifying process *N* reads a waiter count that includes *W*, but before *W* completes its semaphore decrement.  This will allow one future waiter to pass through without blocking.
- A waiting process *W2* arrives in `wait()` between when a notifying process has incremented `can_proceed` and when the last of the previously-waiting processes completes its semaphore decrement.  It is possible in this case that *W2* proceeds immediately instead of some thread *W1* that was already waiting at the time of the notification.  In this case, *W1* would be released by the next notification (unless the same thing happened to it again).
- If two processes attempt to notify at about the same time then one could observe a waiter count that reflected processes that had already been released, but had not yet completed their semaphore decrement.  The likely outcome is that one or more future processes would pass through `wait()` without blocking.

Inasmuch as two of those are analogous to spurious return from a CV wait, they could be addressed via a similar predicate-checking idiom.      That would be tricky given the fact that there is necessarily a gap between a process completing its semaphore decrement and it acquiring a mutex, but perhaps that could be worked around by using an atomic object, so that no mutex is required.

It is also possible that a process dies in `notify()` before incrementing `can_proceed`, such that that notification is ineffective.  I don't account that a weakness specific to the suggested scheme.

Note that SysV semaphores do not themselves reside in or require shared memory.